# but why swing does not paint my component?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a working version of the simplest java gui with a button and a circle which works fine:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
//a gui element shares its events only with classes that implement Actionlistener interface
public class SimpleGui1 implements ActionListener {    
   JButton button;
   JFrame frame;
   ppanel mypanel;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    SimpleGui1 mywindow = new SimpleGui1();
    mywindow.renderWindow();
}  
public void renderWindow(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    button = new JButton("click me");
    mypanel = new ppanel();

    //register my interest to catch button events
    button.addActionListener(this);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mypanel);

    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}   
//button will call this method when clicked (its the callback)
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{       
    frame.repaint();
    button.setText("Clicked!!");
}
}
//i need this to override paintComponent
public class ppanel extends JPanel  {   
    //draw something silly
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);

    Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    GradientPaint gradient =  new GradientPaint(70,70,startColor, 150,150, endColor);
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);
    g2d.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
}
}
```

And then, just for fun, i tried to aggregate the two classes to one like this:

```
public class SimpleGui1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {    
private JButton button;
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel mypanel;


public static void main (String[] args) {
    SimpleGui1 mywindow = new SimpleGui1();
    mywindow.renderWindow();
}

public void renderWindow(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    button = new JButton("click me");
    mypanel = new JPanel();

    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // register my interest to catch button events
    button.addActionListener(this);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mypanel);

    //without this i see only the button
    //frame.add(this);

}
//button will call this method when clicked (its the callback)
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    frame.repaint();
    button.setText("Clicked!!");
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   //super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);

    Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    GradientPaint gradient =  new GradientPaint(70,70,startColor, 150,150, endColor);
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);
    g2d.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
}
}
```

The new class compiles successfully but at run time it draws only the button. For some reason paintComponent is not called and the only way to work correctly is to add the following in renderwindow():

```
 frame.add(this);
```

my question is **why** this behaviour ... why do i have to **add explicitly
the object to my frame** for this version to work properly?

*Tried repaint() and validate() almost everywhere. Does not change much*
*Also i know that i shouldnt be drawing things off EDT and a version with inner classes also alleviates the problem*

Comment: Instead of showing us the code that works, show us the code that doesn't. Trying to read it by mentally copying and pasting code from the first snippet into the second one is not very parctial.

Comment: @JBNizet oh i am sorry i didnt want to verbose you by copying the same things over and over

Comment: "why do i have to add explicitly the object to my frame" well how else would it know what you wanted in the frame? It's the same as what you were doing before when you added a `ppanel` to it.

Comment: A component must be added to a displayed container, attached to a native peer, before it can be painted.  The only way to do this in Swing is by adding the component to a some kind of window directly or in directly. In you first example you do `frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mypanel);`, which adds `ppanel` indirectly to a window container, when the window is made visible, it is painted.  Why would you think it would work any differently for a separate class/pane?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i added the version that does not work for me.. i have to use `frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mypanel);` AND `frame.add(this);` to work

Comment: @gep But even in your updated version, you NEVER add `SimpleGui1` to a displayable container UNTIL you use `frame.add(this)`...Personally, I would discourage you from doing it this way.  Instead, when you want to use `SimpleGUI1`, create an instance of it and add it to an instance of a window.  I'd avoid having a method in the class that does this, but that's me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are right i havent realized what i was adding where..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you have to explicitly add the this object to the content pane. I compiled and tested the following:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
//a gui element shares its events only with classes that implement Actionlistener interface
public class SimpleGui1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {    
       JButton button;
       JFrame frame;
       ppanel mypanel;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);

        Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        GradientPaint gradient =  new GradientPaint(70,70,startColor, 150,150, endColor);
        g2d.setPaint(gradient);
        g2d.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SimpleGui1 mywindow = new SimpleGui1();
        mywindow.renderWindow();
    }  
    public void renderWindow(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("click me");

        //register my interest to catch button events
        button.addActionListener(this);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, this);

        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   
    //button will call this method when clicked (its the callback)
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {       
        frame.repaint();
        button.setText("Clicked!!");
    }
}
```

You need to explicitly add the components in order for this to be painted, it doesn't matter that the component is the object itself!

Comment: yes that did it, thank you @amaurs .. and i am half way there understanding it :)

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that this is your problem:

```
public void renderWindow(){
     //where everything is the same except ofcourse:
     mypanel = new JPanel();
   }
```

Because the mypanel is of type JPanel you are adding a generic panel to the frame and not the object with your overrides.

Try:

```
public void renderWindow(){
 //where everything is the same except ofcourse:
 mypanel = new SimpleGui1();  // or possibly 'this'
}
```

This way your SimpleGui1 class will be added to the frame and can participate in the Swing message queue.

To answer your question about 'why', it is because when you attach a panel to the frame the panel has to have the code to handle messages and overrides.  When you include a JPanel object you don't get any of the custom behavior.  To tell the frame that it should send messages to your class you have to tell the frame about, essentially registering it with the frame.